# How to modify the vector of strings inside the lambda

Tags: c++, string, vector, lambda

How to pass the vector of strings to lambda and copy the characters to vector ?

Here i am capturing the vector as reference but once the for_each is done, all

the strings in "token" vector is empty so "final" string is empty.

```
string encryption(string s) {

    string test;

    std::copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(), back_inserter(test), [](char c)
              {
                  if (isspace(c))
                  {
                      return false;
                  }

                  return true;
              });

    int size = s.size();
    float number = sqrt(size);

    int row = ceil(number);
    int col = floor(number);

    while ((row * col) < size)
    {
        row++;
    }

    std::vector<string> token;
    token.reserve(row);

    for_each(test.begin(), test.end(), [&](char c) mutable
             {
                 static int count = 0;
                 token[count%row] += c;
                 cout << token[count%row] << endl;
                 count++;
             });


    stringstream final;
    std::copy(token.begin(), token.end(), std::ostream_iterator<string>(final, " "));
    return final.str();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you set the vectors *capacity* with the [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) call, but not its *size* (which you set either using the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) or [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)).

In short: Your vector is *empty*, and the loop printing will simply not iterate because of that.

What's worse, because the vector is empty, all indexing into it will be out of bounds and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Simple solution is to set the *size* of the vector:

```
std::vector<string> token(row);
```

Or alternatively

```
std::vector<string> token;
token.resize(row);  // Using *resize* to set the size
```

Answer (score 3):

You have undefined behavior here, as

```
token.reserve(row);
```

allocates enough memory to hold `row` elements, but doesn't change the size of the vector. Hence, indexing `token` inside the lamdba

```
token[count%row] += c;
```

is an out of bounds access. To fix this, change the call to `std::vector::reserve` into one to `std::vector::resize`:

```
token.resize(row);
```